# In Django Project show me UserInfo matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, authentication

Here is views.py code.
In the def index section, I use UserInfo model.Here information store in one to one relation so I write (user__pk=user_id)

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from Login_app.forms import UserForm, UserInfoForm
    from Login_app.models import UserInfo
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
    from django.urls import reverse


def index(request):
    dict={}
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        current_user = request.user
        user_id = current_user.id
        user_basic_info = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)         
        user_more_info = UserInfo.objects.get(user__pk=user_id)
        dict = {'user_basic_info':user_basic_info, 'user_more_info':user_more_info}
    
    return render(request, 'Login_app/index.html', context=dict)
```

Here is models.py code.where I create UserInfo model.It store user,facebook_id,profile_pc.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.


class UserInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    facebook_id = models.URLField(blank=True)

    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'profile_pics', blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: It means you have a user for which there is no `UserInfo` object, so you did not create one when you crated a `User` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make Sure that you have inserted data in `UserInfo` table. For getting date related to one to one field with User table, you don't have to extract user id explicitly. The following code should do it-

```
current_user = request.user
user_more_info= UserInfo.objects.filter(user=current_user).get()
```

Moreover, if you have a field called 'full_name' in User model, you can directly access it -

```
user_full_name=current_user.full_name
```

Comment: Well, there is a couple of ways to do it. Your's also not wrong but you had to extract user_id separately from current _user object.You can get rid off that extra line by using the current_user object directly. Give it a try.

Comment: Great to here that @MDTanimHossain